# Is it possible to have two different texts for the same glossary entry?

Tags: glossaries

I am creating a "symbols" glossary. I would like to be able to have a single entry that has one or more alternate texts that I can somehow switch between each time I reference the glossary item. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{sym:graph}{
    name=\ensuremath{G},
    alttext=\ensuremath{G^\prime},
    description={A graph},
    type=symbolslist
}
```

Where I could have the text (as an example implementation):
`Both \gls{sym:graph} and \glsalt{sym:graph} are graphs.`

What's important is that there is a single entry in the "symbols" glossary, and clicking on either reference navigates to that glossary item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the use of an already existing key like 'plural' or 'user1' (in my opinion a better fit for your intent of an alternative text, see manual p.142 in v4.45), you have also the option to create your own keys (see manual p.80  in v4.45).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}

\glsaddkey
{alttext}           % key
{todo}              % default value
{\glsentryAltText}  %{no link cs} ... command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\GlsentryAltText}  %{no link ucfirst cs} ... command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsAltText}       %{link cs} ... command analogous to \glstext
{\GlsAltText}       %{link ucfirst cs} ... command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSAltText}       %{link allcaps cs} ... command analogous to \GLStext

\newglossaryentry{sym:graph}{
    name=\ensuremath{G},
    user1=\ensuremath{G^1},
    alttext=\ensuremath{G^\prime},
    description={A graph},
    type=symbols,
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
First use of \gls{sym:graph} as well as first use of \glsAltText{sym:graph} and also \glsuseri{sym:graph}
\printsymbols
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `plural` is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{sym:graph}{
    name=\ensuremath{G},
    plural=\ensuremath{G^\prime},
    description={A graph},
    }

\begin{document}

Both \gls{sym:graph} and \glspl{sym:graph} are graphs.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how I feel about repurposing that command.

Comment: What kind of repurposing do you mean? I believe plural does exactly what you ask in the question